# Unable to install Laravel on Ubuntu 18.10 LEMP stack?

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

When running `laravel new` I receive all these errors. I understand what they mean, but I'm curious to why this happenes, on windows it all went through fine.

I installed php, how come Ubuntu throws errors? Does it exclude a lot of things from the php installation? I'm not really sure why its causing so much drama, this is the 10th set of errors I've gone through today and I'm worried I've done something majorly wrong.

I followed this for my LEMP stack: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Also, before I can even use the `laravel` command, I have to run `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` every time I open a terminal. Is there a way to fix this?

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for erusev/parsedown v1.7.2 -> satisfiable by erusev/parsedown[v1.7.2].
    - erusev/parsedown v1.7.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.8.7 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.7].
    - laravel/framework v5.8.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for phar-io/manifest 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by phar-io/manifest[1.0.3].
    - phar-io/manifest 1.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - Installation request for phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.1.4 -> satisfiable by phpunit/php-code-coverage[6.1.4].
    - phpunit/php-code-coverage 6.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 5
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 7.5.7 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[7.5.7].
    - phpunit/phpunit 7.5.7 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 6
    - Installation request for theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by theseer/tokenizer[1.1.0].
    - theseer/tokenizer 1.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 7
    - laravel/framework v5.8.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.2 requires illuminate/console 5.6.*|5.7.*|5.8.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.7].
    - Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-dump-server 1.2.2 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-dump-server[1.2.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which PHP version are you using?

You need mbstring extension installed.

Assuming it's PHP7.2, you can install the dependencies required for Laravel like:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mbstring php7.2-dom php7.2-pdo php7.2-xml php7.2-common php7.2-bcmath php7.2-json php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm php7.2-mysql
```

**Edit**: That LEMP guide doesn't cover php extensions' installation.

Assuimg it's Laravel 5.8, according to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements), you need some extensions installed, too. Updating my answer accordingly

Note: If you need MySQL etc (because you mentioned LEMP) I've also added php7.2-mysql.

Although, like I mentioned in my comments, I'd prefer Ondrej Sury's PPA and install PHP7.3 and its extensions instead.

Comment: I understand this. I'm using PHP 7.2 and have installed it, if you check my question out I ask why its throwing so many errors and have I done something majorly wrong, in windows it works out the box. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @AdamG, Arda is right. When you start fixing problems from top to bottom, you'll see when you fix a thing, it fixes few more lines. Probably you'd need to do it for `ext-dom` too

Comment: @AdamG I strongly suggest Ondrej Sury's PPA for PHP installation. I install his builds on Debian and Ubuntu for almost 6 years, without any issues: https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php . I don't have to deal with any path or other stuff, and they are always up-to-date. I'm almost sure your php7.2-cli's ini file maps extension files from somewhere else, saying it's installed the extension packages already, because that guide doesn't cover installation of PHP extensions.

Comment: @AdamG Updated my answer, now it should install all required extensions if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Vagrant LEMP VM (NginX, Mysql 8 and PHP7.3) with composer 1.10.7, when I try to install any version of Laravel (5.8.6.x, 7.x). I installed php7.3-zip, unzip for linux and returns several errors: unzip -qq failed in most packages
Does anyone have any idea how to solve? Thank you